# Convert enum to NSNumber in swift

Tags: swift, enums

Working in Swift, I'd like to convert an enum (of type Int) into NSNumber and back. I can convert from enum to Number but I can't convert back. What's the recommended approach?

```
enum UpdateMode: Int {
    case Undefined = 0,
         Daily,
         Weekly,
         Monthly
}

var mode = UpdateMode.Weekly
var num: NSNumber = mode.rawValue // this works

// error: 'Int32' is not convertible to 'UpdateMode'
var convertedMode = num.integerValue as UpdateMode
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's an initializer for that:

```
var convertedMode = UpdateMode(rawValue: num.integerValue)
```

note that it's failable, so `convertedMode` is an optional - that to account for the integer not mapped to a valid enum case